# In Excel, how to paste special to the next empty row using visual basic/macro?

Tags: excel, paste, vba

I have four columns on the same sheet.  I want to create a macro so that each time I run the macro the value in column C will be copied and pasted special on the next empty row in Column D.  For example to begin with we have:

```
Column A    Column B    Column C    Column D
1           41          42
```

Column C contains the formula =A1+B1.

Once I run the macro, we would get:

```
Column A    Column B    Column C    Column D
1           41          42          42
```

If I run the macro again with different values in Column A and B, I would get:

```
Column A    Column B    Column C    Column D
10           90          100          42
                                     100
```

and so on.

I attempted the visual basic code:

```
Sub Copy()
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1").PasteSpecial
End Sub
```

But this does not work.  It doesn't paste special and it doesn't find the next empty row in column D.

Could anyone let me know how to write the code properly?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to move down:

```
Sub xCopy()
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1").Value = "" Then
        n = 1
    Else
        n = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End If
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & n).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!!  It seems that when the macro is run multiple times, it is only adding zeros to column D?  was there an error in the code, i wonder?

Comment: It **should** take the current value in cell **C1** and put it in the next available cell in column **D**

Comment: Yes. I tested it on excel 2010 but it doesnt seem to work properly?